# $∃x¬(\varphi ∨ \psi) → ∃x(¬\varphi ∨ ¬\psi)$ and $∃y(\varphi ∧ \psi) → (∀x$ $\varphi ∧ ∀y$ $\psi)$

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

For each of the following formulas, indicate if is or not a first order logic theorem, whatever the formulas $\varphi$ and $\psi$. Justify, showing that exists a natural deduction of the corresponding formula or indicating a language $L$ and formulas $\varphi$ and $\phi$ of $L$ and a structure $A=(A,.^A)$ of $L$, such as $A$ is not a model of the corresponding formula.

- $∃x¬(\varphi ∨ \psi) → ∃x(¬\varphi ∨ ¬\psi)$
- $∃y(\varphi ∧ \psi) → (∀y$ $\varphi ∧ ∀y$ $\psi)$

Comment: Can you show us some effort? First: do you think the statements are theorems or not?

Comment: @Bram28 I think the first one is not a theorem because I not seeing how I can get $∃x(¬φ∨¬ψ)$ from $∃x¬(φ∨ψ)$. The other one looks like it is provable.

Comment: Thank you for copy-pasting your homework assignment into our service. Please stand by while our neural-network algorithm is auto-generating an answer to your question. One of our representatives will be with you shortly. On the meanwhile, please prepare your 16-digit credit card number, including your full name, expiration date and those 3 digits on the back of the card which for some reason are not on the front with the rest of them. Since this is a social-network web service, the cost will be 1 bitcoin per user. Thanks again for choosing to work with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

1st) Consider that $\lnot (\varphi \lor \psi)$ is equivalent to $\lnot \varphi \land \lnot \psi$.

2nd) Consider : "there exists a number that is $=0$ and $\ge 0$".

Comment: What do you mean when you say "free variables"?

Comment: You're right, the quantifier was wrong.

Comment: For 2), if I assume that: $A = \{0,1,2\}$, $\varphi = R^A(n) = \{0,1,2\}$ and $\psi = S^A(n) = \{2\}$ I prove that the statement is false because $∃y(R(y)∧S(y))→(∀y R(y)∧∀y S(y))$ is false. Correct?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - correct.

Comment: For 1), I did it like this: [solution](https://i.gyazo.com/07aa2ced2ab1096268492758dcc95103.jpg) but I don't know if every step is correct.

Comment: can you please verify if my solution is correct? It would meant a lot.